# Date conversion in informatica

Tags: teradata, informatica

I am loading date fields from file to teradata table.
In a file my date format is `mm-dd-yyyy` and in my teradata table the format is `yyyy/mm/dd`.

I used the below function for formatting:

```
To_date(to_char(date field,'mm-dd-yyyy'),'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

But all my records are going in rejected records.
When I checked session log my date field was mentioned as invalid date.

Please help on this.

Comment: In your input file the date column is a string? Then you don't have to do the to_char, it should be **to_date(date field, 'mm-dd-yyyy')** or **date field (date, format 'mm-de-yyyy')**

Comment: Thanks dnoeth I have used to_date(datefield,'mm-dd-yyyy ') and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just use to_date('12-31-2014','mm-dd-yyyy');
It will work

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function.

```
v_PORT(DateTime)-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(INPUTPORT),'MM-DD-YYYY')
   o_PORT(String)--TO_CHAR(v_PORT,'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

It's working.

Comment: HEY - why don't you learn? You MUST NOT include contact data in your posts!